# MechanicalSoup: Cant sign into gmail

Tags: python, authentication, gmail, mechanicalsoup

Trying to sign into a google account using mechanicalsoup library in python. I keep getting an error that says "No valid element named identifier". But, if you look at the html for the google sign in page, you see that there is indeed an element named "identifier". Here is the code that I used:

```
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()

browser.open("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?
```

continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin20&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin")

```
browser.select_form("form")

browser['identifier'] = "username"

browser.submit_selected()
```

Sorry for the cut in the middle of the code. I couldn't correctly indent the lines to make it more neat. Oh, and here is the entire error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/joldb/PycharmProjects/chatroom/testing.py", line 9, in 
browser['identifier'] = "username"
File "C:\Users\joldb\PycharmProjects\chatroom\venv\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\stateful_browser.py", line 103, in **setitem**
self.get_current_form()[name] = value
File "C:\Users\joldb\PycharmProjects\chatroom\venv\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\form.py", line 237, in **setitem**
return self.set(name, value)
File "C:\Users\joldb\PycharmProjects\chatroom\venv\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\form.py", line 278, in set
raise LinkNotFoundError("No valid element named " + name)
mechanicalsoup.utils.LinkNotFoundError: No valid element named identifier

Comment: Does that page rely on javascript?  mechanicalsoup doesn't do javascript.

Comment: Yea i didn't think of that. I just thought you could select the form and input some stuff, and then submit it. EDIT: I forgot to add that i was able to CREATE a google account using mechanicalsoup, with no problems. I would expect to be able to do the same thing with a sign in

Comment: You could do that, if the form were present as plain html in the initial page load.  But if the page uses dynamic javascript to create the form element, you're out of luck.

Comment: Can you show us the entire error traceback message?

Comment: Ah okay. So, as i am kind of a nooby with coding and developing, how would i be able to tell if the page uses javascript for the form? Sure let me edit the post

Comment: After opening the page, you can use `browser.get_current_page()` to see the page source being used by the browser.  Look at that source and see if the form is there, with the fields you expect.

Comment: Nope. The form i saw in the inspect element was not there.

Comment: You may want to use a different browser automation package, such as Selenium, that is javascript-aware.

Comment: I have used selenium in the past. Although, i wanted to try something that wouldn't open a visible window in front of me

Comment: I believe there are "headless" options for Selenium that don't open an actual visible browser window.

Comment: Oh. Nice. So, if i were to use bs4 or requests instead of selenium, what would the advantages/disadvantages be?

Comment: requests/bs4 don't do javascript either, so you'd have the same problem as mechanicalsoup.

Comment: really? Oh. Well i think I will just keep using selenium then. Thank you so much for your time to help me out. Appreciate it.

Comment: Also, one more thing, i have also been currently working on posting a comment to a youutbe livestream using selenium but it won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Nobody can help if you don't show the code.  Open a new question.

Comment: Alrighty then. This comment section has gone too far anyway. Will do that